# Rofi pass list from Python

Tags: python, bash, list

I want to pass a list from python to rofi/bash. How would I do it?

I tried to join the list

```
 choice = "\n".join(links)

 chosen = subprocess.check_output("echo "  + choice  + " | rofi -dmenu -i", shell=True)
```

EDIT:
The code I've posted kinda work. The only Problem is, that everything is one line. So how to convert a python list to a bash list that rofi can process.

Comment: After further investigation I found out that my problem is not about python but rofi or bash in gerneal. Bash script:
´array=(1231 2 3)
entry=$(echo -e "$array" | rofi -dmenu -i)´
is not working as well

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution with the usage of the Popen class https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects
not the best solution I bet there are some better.

I was not able to test it with the `rofi` package.
Please let me know it ti helped.

```py
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

links = ["1","2"]
choice = "\n".join(links)
  
p1 = Popen(["echo", choice], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["rofi", "-demnu", "-i"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()

output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm not very familiar with subprocess/Popen.
This part:
`p2 = Popen(["rofi", "-demnu", "-i"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)`
seems not to work. Rofi seems not to understand what to do and prints:
"Rofi is unsure what to show."
Why are the arguments seperated like this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answe myself:

```
choices = "\n".join(links)
chosen = check_output("echo '" + choices + "' | rofi -dmenu", shell=True)
```

The kind of list rofi or dmenu reads needs to be seperated with \n and the whole thing needs to be in qutoes.